# How to build SPEAK component in Sitecore?

Tags: javascript, mvvm, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-speak-ui

I'm trying to create a simple SPEAK component using Sitecore 7.5 and SPEAK 1.2. The documentation seems slim or outdated on the subject. I tried following this article, but there are lots of holes in it: http://www.dervalp.com/component-in-speak-1-2-client-side/

Can anyone recommend any steps to create a JavaScript SPEAK component?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jakob Chrisensen has a good set of video tutorials on his YouTube! channel:

https://www.youtube.com/user/JakobHChristensen/videos

Answer (score 2):

I raised a bug with Sitecore support with SPEAK 1.2. They say its in technical preview at the moment and not fully supported.

Sitecore.app has moved to Sitecore.Speak.app in Sitecore 7.5 / 8.

However there is this blog post on Speak 1.2, if you still wish to carry on with SPEAK 1.2.

http://laubplusco.net/sitecore-speak-v1-2-goodies/

Answer (score 1):

I have a few open source SPEAK applications on GitHub if these will help you. These were built on Sitecore 7.2 and SPEAK 1.1. You can take the changes to the JS page code in Pierre's blog post and apply it to my examples. They also have patch include files for including new component into SPEAK.

I have TDS packages with these applications so you can see how the core DB is set up for a SPEAK application.

Source

https://github.com/sobek1985/SitecoreSPEAKBulkRolePermissions
https://github.com/sobek1985/SitecoreDataImporter

Modules

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/SPEAK_Data_Importer.aspx
https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/Sitecore_Bulk_Role_Permissions.aspx?sc_lang=en

Martina' s blogs are useful too http://mhwelander.net/category/speak/

Anders has a good JSON component example: http://laubplusco.net/creating-simple-sitecore-speak-json-datasource/

Comment: Thanks but SPEAK v1.2 is so different I can't even get to Sitecore.app. Now it is seems I have to do Sitecore.Speak.Components, but then what? The components have a model and view but are functions?